# Java Swing ignores repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, timer

Basically I need one of my panels to be repainted at least 60 times per second. However I noticed, that if I don't move my mouse, FPS drops to ~5. I wrote program to test it.

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Timer t;
    JLabel l;
    JPanel p;
    long lastT;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();

    }

    public Test(){
        add(p = new JPanel());
        p.add(l = new JLabel("0000000000000000000000000000000"));
        pack();
        lastT = System.nanoTime();
        t = new Timer(10, this);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        l.setText(String.valueOf((time - lastT)));
        repaint();
        lastT = time;
    }

}
```

It shows the interval between frames. If my mouse is inside the window, it changes much faster, if it is outside of window, it changes much slower, similar to my original problem. But the thing is, the number itself is not much different no matter if mouse is inside or outside, which means that Timer is shooting event at same interval. So it means that the repaint() is ignored? How can it be fixed?

Comment: It's working fine for me, try running it on another machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that repaint is never guaranteed to work as the Swing repaint manager will ignore stacked repaint requests -- that is if repaint requests build up and are not able to be handled in a timely fashion due to code being run from the Swing event queue, only the last one is called. Please read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more.

Note however that there is no need to call `repaint()` in your code above, since changing the state of the JLabel's model will trigger a repaint on its own, and this would be a  repaint of just the label itself, something that should be run more efficiently than calling repaint on the entire GUI. Also note that 10 mSec is a very short time slice and a Swing Timer may not be accurately or reliably called at 10 msec.

Comment: Well, I need to call repaint() in my actual application, where timer also updates positions of objects, and render method of those objects is called.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: ok that's a different situation than what you've posted. Never rely on a Swing Timer being completely accurate, and always base your physics on measured time slices. Please read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: also you'll likely want to limit your repainting to the involved rectangle or rectangles, by calling an overload of repaint that accepts a Rectangle parameter.

Comment: I mean I don't rely on timer being accurate, as I calculate `time = System.nano(); delta = time - last_time; last_time = time;` on each Timer fire. I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: when you call `repaint()` on a component, you request that the JVM repaint the entire component. If your animation just changes the images of a small sub-section of the component, then you may wish to call the repaint method overload, `public void repaint(Retangle r)` that takes a Rectangle as a parameter. This will request that the JVM only repaint the rectangular portion that you pass in and not the whole component, and *may* result in improved efficiencies.